# What happens to the memory used by your program after it's finished running?

Tags: python, memory

TL:DR What does python do with a programs allocated memory space after it terminates?

This may seem like a basic question but I want to know what happens to, for example, a python list that contains 1000 ints after I shut down the program.

I ask this because I've recently been working with programs that have quite large dict's and lists. I feel I should manually delete the programs allocated memory space, esspecially if I'm just trying to see if the program runs correctly.

Is there a way to do this in python, does python do this automatically?

Should I even be worried about it at all?

Comment: The OS reclaims it, and that's that.

Comment: All major, modern operating systems will free the memory allocated by a process once the process terminates.

Comment: Garbage collection can be something to research. It's not Python specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details depend on the OS, but in general, when a process exits, the OS deletes everything it touched - memory, file handles, sockets, etc. At least, it tries to.

Comment: Thanks for the help!